# git remote add -f doesn't add tracking branches

Tags: git, github, git-remote

I'm cloning a fork of a project in github and want to set up an upstream remote to track the original project. As I understand things, fetching the upstream remote should create tracking branches of the remotes branches in my local repo, but git isn't doing that, so either I misunderstand the process or I'm doing something wrong.

I've tried both

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/dude1/awesome-project.git
git fetch upstream
```

and

```
git remote add -f upstream https://github.com/dude1/awesome-project.git
```

and when I do `git branch -a` after either set of operations all I have is my origin tracking branches.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Adding remote repository does not track all the branches on remote repo. 
To track remote branches, you should do

- If you don't have branch on your local repo and want to create one.

  ```
  git branch {branch_name} upstream/{branch_name}
  ```

where {branch_name} represents your branch name.

It will create a branch in your local repo and will track remote branch which you have specified.

- If you have branch on your local repo and want to push it to remote repo,

  ```
  git push upstream {branch_name_on_local}:{branch_name_in_repo}
  ```